# How can I use regular expression find all img attribute?

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this regular expression find img and it's attribute.

```
 var str = '<img src="/abc/2016-03-22/20160322101114771.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 318px;" alt="abc"><img  src="/abc/20160322101157885.jpg" style="width: 497px; height: 334px;" alt=""/>'

 var reg = /<img(\s*([^=>]+)="([^">]*?)"\s*?)+?\/>/

 var matchs = str.match(reg)

 console.log(matchs)
```

this is result:

```
[ '<img  src="/abc/20160322101157885.jpg" style="width: 497px; height: 334px;" alt=""/>',
  ' alt=""',
  'alt',
  '',
  index: 96,
  input: '<img src="/abc/2016-03-22/20160322101114771.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 318px;" alt="abc"><img  src="/abc/20160322101157885.jpg" style="width: 497px; height: 334px;" alt=""/>' ]
```

I want find all attribute from the result, but only last one.

what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're using `RegEx` for simple `DOM` parsing, you could do this:

```
var str = '<img src="/abc/2016-03-22/20160322101114771.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 318px;" alt="abc"><img  src="/abc/20160322101157885.jpg" style="width: 497px; height: 334px;" alt=""/>';
// Create dummy element and append string
var dummy = document.createElement('div');
dummy.innerHTML = str;
// Fill the output object
var output = {};
var imgs = dummy.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0, len = imgs.length; i < len; i++) {
    var attsObj = {};
    for(var j = 0, atts = imgs[i].attributes, jen = atts.length; j < jen; j++) {
        attsObj[atts[j].nodeName] = atts[j].nodeValue;
    }
    output[i] = attsObj;
}
```

No need for that noise here, now you have a nice object:

```
output = {
    0: {
        "alt": "abc",
        "src": "/abc/2016-03-22/20160322101114771.jpg",
        "style": "width: 500px; height: 318px;"
    },
    1: {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "/abc/20160322101157885.jpg",
        "style": "width: 497px; height: 334px;"
    }
}
```

However, if you just want the last `IMG` tag, you can do this:

```
var output = {};
var imgs = dummy.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0, atts = imgs[imgs.length - 1].attributes, len = atts.length; i < len; i++) {
    output[atts[i].nodeName] = atts[i].nodeValue;
}
```

And now the `output` object has the attributes of the last `IMG` tag from the string and can be accessed like so:

```
var src = output['src']; // "/abc/20160322101157885.jpg"
var style = output['style']; // "width: 497px; height: 334px;"
var alt = output['alt']; // ""
```

No need for expressions here when JavaScript has the `DOM` built in for handling HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is probably unnecessary.  Since you've tagged this as JavaSciprt, you can get all the attributes using a JavaScript query selector and looping over the attributes.  Something like this would work:

**HTML**

```
<img src="/abc/2016-03-22/20160322101114771.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 318px;" alt="abc">

<img  src="/abc/20160322101157885.jpg" style="width: 497px; height: 334px;" alt=""/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

//loop over all the images in the dom
for (var h = 0; h < images.length; h++) {
    var el = images[h];

  //loop over all the attributes for the matched image
  console.log('Arrtibutes for:');
  console.log(el)
    for (var i = 0, atts = el.attributes, n = atts.length, arr = []; i < n; i++){
    //do what you need with the values here
    console.log(atts[i].nodeName + ': ' + atts[i].nodeValue);
    }
  console.log('---');
}
```

**Output**

> Arrtibutes for:
>   <img src=​"/​abc/​2016-03-22/​20160322101114771.jpg" style=​"width:​ 500px;​  height:​ 318px;​" alt=​"abc">​
>   src: /abc/2016-03-22/20160322101114771.jpg
>   style: width: 500px; height: 318px;
>   alt: abc
>   ‐‐‐
>   Arrtibutes for:
>   <img src=​"/​abc/​20160322101157885.jpg" style=​"width:​ 497px;​ height:​ 334px;​" alt>​
>   src: /abc/20160322101157885.jpg
>   style: width: 497px; height: 334px;
>   alt:
>   ‐‐‐

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/7urra3d8/

Hope that helps!

Comment: No selector required, all the img elements are available as [*document.imges*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#dom-document-images). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '<img src="/abc/2016-03-22/20160322101114771.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 318px;" alt="abc"><img  src="/abc/20160322101157885.jpg" style="width: 497px; height: 334px;" alt=""/>';

var reg = /<img\s* [^<>]*>/g, match, matches = [];

while(match = reg.exec(str)) {

    matches.push(match[0]);   

}
console.log(matches);
```

1. The `<img>` is not an attribute, but a html tag.
2. to get all results, you have to loop.

Answer (score 0):

For an approach that does not include `RegExp` you could utilize `DOMParser()` to create a document fragment including string parsed to `img` elements, `Array.prototype.map()`, `attributes` to iterate `img` attributes return an array containing an object for each name , value pair  at `img` element

```js
var str = '<img src="/abc/2016-03-22/20160322101114771.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 318px;" alt="abc"><img  src="/abc/20160322101157885.jpg" style="width: 497px; height: 334px;" alt=""/>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html");
var attrs = [].map.call(doc.images, function(img) {
  return [].map.call(img.attributes, function(attr) {
    var imgAttrs = {}; imgAttrs[attr.name] = attr.value;
    return imgAttrs
  })
})

console.log(attrs)
```